# MailChimp keeps height of image when replaced

Tags: image, attributes, height, mailchimp

I've set an image to be editable in a custom template that I've made for MC, but when I edit the image and replace it, it maintains the height of the previous one. I've added these attributes for the img container:

```
<img mc:edit="myImage" src="" height="auto" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you're specifying two attributes for the height and they're both set to auto. You're telling MC to expand the image to the full width so the height will be set by the dimensions and aspect ratio of the image.

You can either specify height or width to achieve the look you want, or you can physically edit the image to the height you want by clicking on the element, selecting 'edit' and then 'resize' in the photo editor.

Comment: I don't want to specify height as it's a responsive image. And I shouldn't have to either.

Comment: This is what Mailchimp recommend for fluid images:  
<img src="" alt="" height="" width="" class="emailImage" />  

Then you need to add this to your css:  
<style type="text/css">  
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){  
        .emailImage{  
            height:auto !important;  
            max-width:600px !important;  
            width: 100% !important;  
        }  
    }  
</style>

Comment: Thanks, yes I've seen that but it doesn't work when I try and apply it to my template.